# error when deploying react app to github pages: fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No error

Tags: reactjs, git, github, github-pages, ssh-keys

This is my first time deploying an app to GitHub pages. I have an app in react which I want to host it in GitHub pages. I followed different tutorials (linked below) which almost introduce the same approach. everything is OK but at the end when I run `npm run deploy`, I receive this error : 
. I'm somehow new to GitHub and haven't set any config related to SSH key. Is it related? or any idea what the problem is?

[image]

[tutorial I](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F8s4Ng-re0E)
 [tutorial II](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Y-PqBH-htk)

I tried to solve this issue by SSH. However, I get this error on "npm run deploy" and I'm stuck

[image]

Comment: @AjeetShah, any idea why that happens? I have set the global config for username and email in my Git.

Comment: Also, make sure `$ git config --global --list` and `git config --local --list` prints your correct email for the repo.

Comment: Or you can try adding: `"gh-pages -d build --user \"Your Name <your.name@email.com>\""` in your npm script, providing your name and email. I tried to reproduce your problem but could not even after setting incorrect email at local and global config, probably because I am using ssh to authenticate with github.

Comment: Thank you for your help. No success after including username and email in "gh-pages -d build" or "npm run deploy"; though the username and email was  correctly printed when running "git config --list" . I think I have to try ssh.

Comment: yes. the only thing that doesn't work is "npm run deploy"

Comment: Try [this](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/error-permission-denied-publickey) to debug Permission Denied error.

Comment: well. I had to recreate the ssh and test the solution again with a new empty project and repo. And it worked this time ! I don't have any idea why I couldn't deploy without ssh as well as for the first time I created ssh. 
Thank you for the help @AjeetShah