# Error when deploying my react app to github pages

Tags: reactjs, github, github-pages

I am getting below error when deploying my react app using gh-pages:

[image: please solve the error i'm deploy react-app to Github]

Comment: [Similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62095934/2873538), you will have to follow the comments there and probably self-answer when you find an answer. It is authentication problem, check your global git config email. Finally, you may want to switch to SSH to solve it.

Comment: result not get yet

Comment: Are you able to git pull and git push from and to the repo? Are you using http or ssh? Also, make sure your git local and global config (email) are same and correct for the GitHub account.

Comment: `gh-pages -d build --user \"Your Name <your.name@email.com>\ "` Try this command.

Comment: email of gmail ?

Comment: gh-pages -d build --user \"Your Name <your.name@email.com>\this command not work